# Moving Layout up

Tags: android, button, layout, onclick

In my android app my want to move whole layout up WITHOUT keyboard. 
For example on button click, my whole layout goes up and file chooser appears from bottom.

What library should I use for that??

Answer (score 2):

You could use a RelativeLayout :

Just set your MovingLayout above your file chooser layout.

Your file chooser layout can be set in visibility gone.

And on your button click just switch the visibility of your file chooser layout to visible.